# 2D Heat Transfer - Overflow Error

Tags: python, numpy, simulation

I was trying to simulate 2D heat tranfer in Aluminum with python using the following formula:

dT/dt = K*(d^2T/d^2x + d^2T/d^2y)

Source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V00p-TgQML0

The python code is working with dx = dy = 1 (mm) but if dx and dy get smaller I get an overflow error which I don't know how to avoid.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from copy import deepcopy
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import time


x = 11
y = 11

sd = 1
nx = x*sd
ny = y*sd

dx = 1/float(sd)
dy = dx

#Initial Temperature
T0 = 25

# Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity  
# Aluminium Thermal diffusivity (mm**2/s) 
K = 97

#Time
t0 = 0
te = 1
st = 1000
dt = 1/float(st)


#Iterations
N = (te - t0)*st

T = np.zeros(shape=(nx, ny))

T[:,:] = T0

# Dirichlet Condition
T[nx/2,ny/2] = 1000


MM = []

for n in range(N):

    Tb = deepcopy(T)

    for i in range(nx):
        for j in range(ny):

            #Neumann Boundary Conditions
            #TOP
            if i == 0:
                T[i,j] = Tb[i+1,j]

            #RIGHT
            elif j == ny1-1 and i != 0 and i != nx1-1: 
                T[i,j] = Tb[i,j-1]

            #BOTTOM
            elif i == nx-1:  
                T[i,j] = Tb[i-1,j]

            #LEFT
            elif j==0 and i != 0 and i != nx-1:
                T[i,j] = Tb[i,j+1]

            else:

                T[i,j] = Tb[i,j] + K*(dt/dx**2)*(Tb[i+1,j]+Tb[i-1,j]+Tb[i,j+1]+Tb[i,j-1]-4*Tb[i,j])
            T[nx/2,ny/2] = 200

    MM.append(T.copy())

fig = plt.figure()
pcm = plt.pcolormesh(MM[0])
plt.colorbar()

# Function called to update the graphic
def step(i):
    if i >= len(MM): return 0
    pcm.set_array(MM[i].ravel())
    plt.title("Time: {0} s\n".format(i*dt))
    plt.draw()

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, step, interval=3)
plt.show()
```

I order to reproduce the overflow error change the value of sd to 10 (each mm will be divided in 10 elements).

Comment: Hi, what are nx1 and ny1? are they nx, and ny respectivally?

Comment: Wow, I just ran it and it's really cool. However, I can not think of a way to fix that error the only thing that I can think of would be changing the data type to like long ints or something.

Comment: @Ouss I just changed ny1 and nx1 to nx and ny because they were not defined.

Comment: @Ouss yes you were right! ny1 and nx1 should be replaced by ny nx, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `T[i,j]` is diverging and reaching very hight + and - values, and at some point reaching the limit of the double_scale type.

You could check that by adding `print(T[i,j])` after `T[i,j] = Tb[i,j] + K*(dt/dx**2)*(Tb[i+1,j]+Tb[i-1,j]+Tb[i,j+1]+Tb[i,j-1]-4*Tb[i,j])` in the case of `sd=10` and `st=1000`.

This is not a python or numpy problem, but rather a numerical math problem that occurs when trying to numerically solve stiff differential equations with the method you are using.

When you decide to solve with a higher spacial resolution, you should also solve with a higher time resolution as well. I've tested the code and it works for: `sd=2`, `st=5000` and for `sd=4`, `st=10000`. You see the pattern.

Or use a better numerical solution for your differential equation. Like Backward differentiation formulas (BDF) where you can take bigger time steps without causing the numerical solver to diverge. Look here for inspiration:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html

Comment: thank you for the answer. Im trying to understand implicit methods in order to solve the partial differential equation. Would be possible that you write me a solution with the BDF for the pde in this question?

Answer (score 2):

The heart of the algorithm is

```
T[i,j] = Tb[i,j] + K*(dt/dx**2)*(Tb[i+1,j]+Tb[i-1,j]+Tb[i,j+1]+Tb[i,j-1]-4*Tb[i,j])
```

Focus on the coefficient of Tb[i,j] here: it is `1 - 4*K*(dt/dx**2)`. For the algorithm to work, this has to be a positive number; otherwise you create ice from fire (going positive to negative), the solution makes no physical sense and the numbers explode.

So, make sure that `K*(dt/dx**2)` is less than 1/4. This means that when dx becomes smaller, dt may need to be reduced as well. For example, K=1 and dx=0.001 will require dt < 2.5e-7.